# Regex in Tuckey UrlRewrite

Tags: java, regex, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using [Tuckey URLRewrite](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) and I need a rule which accepts everything except "/" or "\"

I have wrote a rule but tuckey shows unending exceptions and doesn't load the page

```
    <rule>
        <from>^/post/([^/\n\\]+)/type/([a-z]+)$</from>
        <to>/post/?slug=$1&amp;type=$2</to>
    </rule>
```

From [regexr](http://www.regexr.com) I have verified that this expression "([^/\n\]+)"  will select everything except  "/" or "\" But i am getting exceptions. Am I missing something?

Here are the exceptions:

```
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase.matchesBase(RuleBase.java:205)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRule.matches(NormalRule.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRuleProcessing(RuleChain.java:83)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.process(RuleChain.java:137)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:144)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
```

.
.
continues..

Comment: How are **everything except "/"** and `^/post/([^/\n\\]+)/type/([a-z]+)$` same?

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying but I have updated my question

Comment: What URL did you enter when you got this exception?

Comment: it was  
http://localhost:8080/myapp/post-page.jsp/to-defeat-fear/type/random

Comment: But your rule is matching `/post/` at the beginning and you have `post-page.jsp` ?

Comment: oh it's actually localhost:8080/myapp/post/to-defeat-fear/type/random . I changed post-page.jsp to post in web.xml

Comment: ok try a simple regex first: `<from>^/post/([^/]+)/type/([.+)$</from>` and see if exception goes away. btw you haven't provided full stack trace here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68957/discussion-between-waqar-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP had rules like this:

```
<rule> 
<from>^/post</from> 
<to>/post/</to> 
</rule> 

<rule> 
<from>^/post/([^/]+)</from> 
<to>/post/?slug=$1</to> 
</rule> 

<rule> 
<from>^/post/([^/]+)/type/([a-z]+)$</from> 
<to>/post/?slug=$1&amp;type=$2</to> 
</rule>
```

Clearly the problem is ordering of rules here. Since first pattern: `^/post` is overriding anything that starts with `/post` and causing below patterns like `^/post/([^/]+)/type/([a-z]+)$` to be ignore completely.

These rules need to be reordered like this:

```
<rule> 
<from>^/post/([^/]+)/type/([a-z]+)$</from> 
<to>/post/?slug=$1&amp;type=$2</to> 
</rule> 

<rule> 
<from>^/post/([^/]+)</from> 
<to>/post/?slug=$1</to> 
</rule> 

<rule> 
<from>^/post</from> 
<to>/post/</to> 
</rule>
```

i.e. **Keep generic catch-all type rules below specific targeted ones.**